# app get forced closed , when TextView is changed according to radio button

Tags: android, radio-button

My app was running fine until i added the radio buttons , it started getting forced closed when i wrote this code to change the TextView according to radio button. plz help me out..

AND THE APP ISI'T SHOWING ANY ERROR.

public class ContactUs extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener  {

```
RadioGroup rg;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_us);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    Button home=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Home1);
    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent myintent= new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivitySrm.class);
            startActivityForResult(myintent,0);

        }
    });
    TextView textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setClickable(true);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    String text = "<a href='http://www.srmuniv.ac.in'>SRM universtiy</a>";
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

    rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}


/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_us, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:     

        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
}
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg1)
    { case R.id.r1:
        TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textyo);
        t1.setText("kjl");
        break;
    case R.id.r2:
        TextView t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textyo);
        t2.setText("ooo");
        break;
    case R.id.r3:TextView t3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textyo);
    t3.setText("kjl");
        break;
    case R.id.r4:TextView t4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textyo);
    t4.setText("kjl");
        break;


    }
}


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



}
```

Comment: Please consider posting as codeblock-formatted text instead of inline images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to reference your RadioGroup view from xml to Activity's RadioGroup rg variable.
I can't find anywhere you reference your radiogroup from xml to your rg variable.
Just do

```
    rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg1);
```

before you set any listener to RadioGroup.

For each RadionButton you have `android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"` and you haven't implemented any method like `onRadioButtonClicked(View v)` this in your activity. As i can see you don't need to listen for `onClick` when any of the radion button is clicked since you have already took care of that via `onCheckChanged` method of `OnCheckedChangeListener`.

Just by removing `android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"` should fix your problem.

Comment: can you paste the exception from your debug log by editing your question?

Comment: i saw errors in the LOGCAT ... and i will also post the exception from debug

Comment: @krips you should accept my answer by checking it, of course if my answer helps you.Not only it helps future users to find which answer they should follow but it encourage developers like you and me to contribute more and more in the community :) .

Comment: yeh that's the point. and do you know code  how to send data from your android app to local host. its like having a registration form and storing the entered data to a local host.

Comment: yes i have done it previously but for that i had server guy doing his thing since i was only handling the end-user side. nevertheless if you face any problem while implementing post a question in stackoverflow like you did for this question because there is a high probability that someone faced the exact same problem before and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Run it in the debugger.  You will get a stack trace when it crashes.  From that, you will at least see the line of code where the failure happens.  One thing to note, look for "caused by" in the stack trace - that will help you find the place in your code (rather than the Android system) where the failure occurred.